# Permissão correta para diretório wp-admin do WordPress

Tags: wordpress, file-permission

Qual a permissão correta para atribuir ao diretório wp-admin do WordPress? 644 ou 755?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como padrão o Wordpress atribui a permissão `755` e na sua documentação a recomendação é que você não precisa alterar as definições que ele atribui como padrão.

O que você precisa se preocupar é que deve deixar a padrão `644` para o `wp-config.php` ou se preferir uma segurança mais garantida pode deixar na `600` (teste para ver se não vai dar algum problema em sua instalação).

Deixe também `644` para o .htacess ou `604` (pode ser que alguns plugins precise de pelo menos `644`.

Outro ponto importante é não deixar permissões `777` pois deixa totalmente gravável, onde pode ser uma porta para hackers e arquivos maliciosos.

## Confira as documentações Oficiais:

### [- Mudando Permissões de Arquivos](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Mudando_Permiss%C3%B5es_de_Arquivos)

### [- Blindando o WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Blindando_o_WordPress)